# change the styling depending on a prop value material ui datepicker conditiona css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am still fairly recent to react and I am facing a new issue that I can't seem to grab my head around. I am using react 16, the version before the hooks( I cannot change this, the react app I use works inside other program that only supports up until this version), and I am using material ui.

I am using date picker like this:

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  textField: {
    color: COLORS.text,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.backgroundColor,
    '&:focus': {
      color: COLORS.text,
      backgroundColor: COLORS.backgroundColor,
    },
    '&:hover': {
      cursor: disabled ? 'disabled' : 'pointer',
    },
  },
});

class DatePickers extends Component {
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    const isPicked = e.target.value;
    onChange(this.props.value, isPicked);
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, partialDayKey, value, disabled } = this.props;

    return (
      <TextField
        id={`${partialDayKey}-datepicker`}
        type="date"
        disabled={disabled}
        name={`${partialDayKey}-datepicker`}
        value={value || '0000-00-00'}
        InputProps={{
          classes: {
            input: classes.textField,
          },
        }}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(DatePickers);
```

I want to change the hover styling depending if the value of disabled is coming as true or false but I can't change it before declaring the props and I also can't move styles to after the props because then I can't use it on the last line of the file.

Not sure how to do the conditional css in this case.
I get an error like this ofc because the disabled keyword doesn't get recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample code for access props

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  textField: {
    '&:hover': {
      cursor:(props)=> props.disabled ? 'disabled' : 'pointer',
    },
  },
});
```